# Not getting sim informations

Tags: android, wifi, sim-card, telephonymanager

In my application I am checking Sim is present or not by using `simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT` . If Sim is present I am collecting all Sim information like Sim operator name, Sim country etc. If I switch off the WiFi, I get Sim absent even it is present and I don't get any Sim details.( Telephone manager not accessing sim when wifi not connected.)

1. Is there any other way to get Sim information when WiFi is off.

```java
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
  ((TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
int simState = telephonyManager.getSimState();
if (simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT){
        Log.d("hello", "network disconnected"); 
        operatorParam.add("Not found");
        operatorParam.add("Not found");
        operatorParam.add("Not found");
        operatorParam.add("Not found");
        operatorParam.add("Not found");
        operatorParam.add("Not found");

    } else {

        Log.d("hello", "network connected");
        if (telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName() != null) {
            operatorParam.add(telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName());
            Log.d("operator", "getoperator name not null: "
                    + telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName());

        } else {
            operatorParam.add("Not found");
        }

        if (telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName() != null) {
            operatorParam.add(telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName());
        } else {
            operatorParam.add("Not found");
        }

        if (telephonyManager.getSimOperator() != null) {
            operatorParam.add(telephonyManager.getSimOperator());
        } else {
            operatorParam.add("Not found");
        }

        if (telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber() != null) {
            operatorParam.add(telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber());
        } else {
            operatorParam.add("Not found");
        }

        if (telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso() != null) {
            operatorParam.add(telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso());
        } else {
            operatorParam.add("Not found");
        }

        if (telephonyManager.getSubscriberId() != null) {
            operatorParam.add(telephonyManager.getSubscriberId());
        } else {
            operatorParam.add("Not found");
        }


       }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You added the permissions to your manifest?

Comment: ya i added android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE  permission

Comment: but there is no relationship between wifi or siminfo as i known

Comment: but when I off the wifi I get as sim absent

Comment: provide more code then you will get more help because it is not possible when WIFI is  OFF then SIM is absent

Comment: I added the code plz go through

Comment: your SIM info code is looking perfect can you edit post with full class code plz